# How to pass environment variables to a non-interactive shell (with example)?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, scripting

In a sh script another sh script is started with `su -l <user> -c /path/to/script.sh`. As far as I understood `script.sh` will be run in a non-interactive shell. The official documentation tries to explain how to set variables in such a non-interactive shell, namely pass them in `BASH_ENV`[http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html ]. This is obviously an insufficient explanation for a beginner and there's no (real) example (didn't find one in $SEARCH_ENGINE neither).

```
if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
```

can mean mean a lot [1]. Can someone please give an example of an environment  variable passed to a non-interactive shell.

Just to make sure: the difference between login and non-login as well as interactive and non-interactive are clear for me (https://superuser.com/questions/636219/where-should-i-export-an-environment-variable-so-that-all-combinations-of-bash-d or referenced link if anyone is interested).

---

[1]I tried

- `BASH_ENV="\\$PATH=$PATH\\n\\$JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" su -l artifactory -c echo $JAVA_HOME`
- `BASH_ENV="\$PATH=$PATH\n\$JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" su -l artifactory -c echo $JAVA_HOME`
- `su -l artifactory -c echo $JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is an `sh` script - as in, it explicitly references `#!/bin/sh` - which might still be `bash` but would be like invoking it with `--posix --no-rc --no-profile` - then you can specify the `ENV` file with the `ENV` environment variable:

```
ENV=/path/to/rcfile sh
```

Specific variables need either to be declared on the command-line - as above for `$ENV` - or else with `export`. For example, for `$PATH` you do:

```
export "PATH=$PATH:/some/more/paths"; sh
```

The `$BASH_ENV` variable you reference is not a file you need to source - and it isn't interpreted anyway when `bash` is invoked as `sh` - but is rather a path to a file that is sourced when a non-interactive `bash` shell is invoked - such as with a script that specifies the:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

...or whatever bang line.

Another way you might like to invoke your script/shell is with the `env` utility. It can be used to explicitly remove values from the environment, or else, as is usually easiest, to wipe it clean from the start:

```
env - BASH_ENV=/path/to/rcfile /usr/bin/bash /some/script/file
```

That will tell `env` to invoke the `/usr/bin/bash` command - with all its arguments appended - with the `$BASH_ENV` environment variable specified, but otherwise with a clean environment entirely.