# Linux environment variable substitution

Tags: shell-script

I have a environment variable called NAME

```
export NAME="xyz"
```

and inside a file test.txt , I have a line

```
name=$NAME
```

I read the file and assigned the line to a variable y

```
y=`cat test.txt`
```

Now I am printing the variable y

```
echo $y
```

How can I get an output of `name=xyz` instead `name=$NAME`?

Comment: where is your `export NAME="xyz"`?

Comment: export NAME="xyz" is in the bash shell session ,
name=$NAME         is in the file

Comment: have you [looked at this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-non-interactive-shell-with-example)?

Comment: Are you wanting to refactor and not use the exported environmental variable? Your problem is not entirely clear.

Comment: That is not seems simple explanation for beginners like me

Comment: @datUser i'm gathering that his env variable is not available in the shell script.  i asked him where he set it, but the question was misunderstood.

Comment: If the environmental variable is causing you grief, I would suggest trying something more simple like passing the value you need from the system as a shell argument, `./script.sh someArgument` and accessing it with `$1`.

Comment: I don’t have a script file , Everything is done in a single bash shell

Comment: This is not the problem of  evronmwng variable scope , if you assign y=“name=$NAME” , and then if you print y . You will get name=xyz as result

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement `eval` for this particular usage.  I'll explain using the command line:

1. export $ABC (as you export $NAME)

   ```
   $ grep ABC .bashrc
   export ABC="xyz"
   ```
2. set the variable in your txt file

   ```
   $ cat test.txt
   name=$ABC
   ```
3. set the $y variable to the output of `cat test.txt`

   ```
   $ y=`cat test.txt`
   ```
4. `eval` $y

   ```
   $ eval $y
   ```
5. now name is set:

   ```
   $ echo $name
   xyz
   ```

Comment: thx @datUser for the edit

Comment: Hi, What I need is, a string , name=xyz . envsubst is a solution , but I found some example where a file is given as argument to it. Can we give the variable $y as input to envsubst program

Comment: You have not explained well why you need to do what it is you are doing.

Comment: I have to read the line name=$NAME from a file and reaplce the env variable $NAME in it and would get a result of name=xyz (consider that value of NAME in env is xyz) as output. 

I am using this output to grep another string.